# How to create a template file for Categories?

Tags: templating, categories

below is my categories url.

http://example.com/index.php?p=categories/vaporizers

i create a template files for categories like

```
templates/categories/index.html
templates/categories/_entry.html
```

my index.html is not called when categories view. please tell me where i create a mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a category you will need to tell craft which template to load:

[image]

So for your example you would put `categories/index` in there and you should find the template gets loaded when you visit the category url.

[See more about templating in the docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating-overview)